# Initializing Halide Buffer in C++

Tags: c++, buffer, halide

I'm trying to initialize Halide Buffer with a C++ 1D array. Given some other posts online, this is what I've got so far:

```
Image<float> in(Buffer(type_of<float>(), size_x, 0, 0, 0, NULL, in_ptr));
```

Where in_ptr is a pointer to my C++ array. 
When I run this I get the following error:

> error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
>      Image in(Buffer(type_of(), padded_size * (jb + 1), 0, 0, 0, NULL, d_In));

So I changed my code to:

`Image<float> in(Buffer<float>(type_of<float>(), size_x, 0, 0, 0, NULL, in_ptr));`

But that doesn't match any of the constructors either but I couldn't find any good documentations on how to initialize a Buffer.

Is it even possible to do something like this? How can I use a C++ 1D or 2D array to initialize Halide buffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Buffer type changed recently, which is why the stuff you're finding online is not useful. To make a buffer that points to an array, use one of these two constructors:

https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/src/runtime/HalideBuffer.h#L631

```
float my_array[10];
Halide::Buffer<float> buf(my_array); // Infers the size from the type
```

https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/src/runtime/HalideBuffer.h#L665

```
float *my_pointer = ...
Halide::Buffer<float> buf(my_pointer, 10); // Accepts a pointer and some sizes
```

2D works similarly:

```
float my_array[30][20]
Halide::Buffer<float> buf(my_array); // Makes a 20x30 array
```

or equivalently,

```
float *my_pointer = ...
Halide::Buffer<float> buf(my_pointer, 20, 30);
```

Neither of these constructors makes a copy of the data - they just refer to the existing array.

Comment: Is there a constructor that makes a copy of the data instead of pointing to the array?

Comment: You can force a copy to the device `buf.copy_to_device(halide_opencl_device_interface())`

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Halide, you likely want:

    `Buffer<float, 1> my_buffer(in_ptr, size_x);`

This will create `my_buffer` pointing to `in_ptr`. The 1 in the template parameters is the number of dimensions. For larger numbers of dimensions, when passing prepopulated memory, strides may have to be specified as well. (The above assumes the data `in_ptr` points to is densely packed -- that is each element is at an index one greater than the previous in `in_ptr`.)

The syntax around this changed recently, but with the goal of making usage easier and more consistent.